# Configuración correcta Typings para Nodejs y express

Tags: nodejs, express, typings, vscode

Cuando instalo el Nodejs y expresss para Typings de VS Code me saca este mensaje y otros 2 mas:

```
typings INFO reference Stripped reference "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/fb2e78984b7076eda628892770a4314d618ac0d7/node/node.d.ts" during installation from "express-serve-static-core"
express
└── (No dependencies)

serve-static
└── (No dependencies)

express-serve-static-core
└── (No dependencies)
```

¿Es correcta esta instalación? ¿Qué debería añadirle?

Comment: Amigo, dale formato a tu pregunta y se más claro con ella.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas esto le ayude(link ingles):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs

```
npm install -g typings
```

---

```
typings install node --ambient
typings install express serve-static express-serve-static-core --ambient
```

Comment: Eso lo intente ya. El problema es que descarge VS Code y es un .zip que tiene dentro un ejecutable y no se instala. Entonces mediante la misma ayuda que oferece el enlace que me dices arriba ejecuto los pasos que me van explicando y el problema es que despues de ejecutar el segundo comando de arriba es que me o los mensajes en la misma consola que puse en la pregunta inicial. Entonces como el Code no me reconoce el tipo del parametro __dirname pienso que no se hallan ejecutado los comandos de instalacion de typings correctamente.